# How to send textbox and datatable value into controller from view?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, datatable, viewmodel

I am new to MVC. I have a datatable, that load data from full calendar. In same page I have 3 text boxes too. Text boxes are comes under header view model and table comes under detail view model. How to pass those values from table and textbox together into controller. Got completely stuck and no ides, but some how, I tried few codes.

**My view:**

```
@model IList<Model.ViewModel.DetailVM>
...
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Master", FormMethod.Post, new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<div class="col-lg-3">
     <label>Description</label>
     @Html.TextBox("Description", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Description" })
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3">
     <label>Code</label>
    @Html.TextBox("Code", null, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Enter Code" })
 </div>
 <div class="col-lg-3 text-center">
     <br />
     <input id="chkBoxIsActive" name="chkBoxIsActive " type="checkbox" />
     <label>Is Active</label>
</div>
 <table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%;" id="CalendarSelection" class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd">
 <thead>

     <tr class="gridheader">
         <td valign="middle" align="center" style="width: 2%;"></td>
         <td style="width: 50%;">Calendar Date</td>
         <td style="width: 50%;">Description</td>
     </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
     <tr>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
         <td></td>
     </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
<div class="btn-group">
<button type="submit" id="btnSave" onclick="Save();" name="btnSave" class="btn btn-block btn-success btn-flat"><span class="hide-on-mobile">Save</span>&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-save"></i></button>
</div>
}
```

**Script:**

```
<script>
    function Save() {
            var data = ('#CalendarSelection').DataTable().$('input,select,textarea').serialize();

            $.ajax({
                url: '/Master/Create/',
                data: data,
                success: function () {
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function () {
                    alert('failure');
                }
            });
        }
    </script>

**Master Controller**


[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string[] data)
        {
            return View();
        }
```

**ViewModel:**

```
 public class CalenderVM
    {
       public string Id { get; set; }

        public string CalenderYear { get; set; }

       public string Description { get; set; }

       public string Code { get; set; }

        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }

         public class DetailVM
    {
        public DateTime [] CalenderDate { get; set; }

        public string[] Description { get; set; }
    }
```

Previously, I used one viewmodel alone to send data from view to controller. As, detail and header in two different view model in same page, I dont know how to send it to controller, How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not using type in ajax request so httpGet method will run when ajax called.

You need to send the ajax response in the network.